# Prevent Azure Live Metrics Stream from logging every poll to queue

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

This started happening recently. At first I thought it might be because i turned on App Service logs. However after turning them off my Live Metrics Stream is still flooded with messages of every poll to every queue that any of my functions have input bidnidngs too.

[image: Logs screenshot]

The Messages contain little value, only stating that the queue was polled, the number of messages found and how long it took. This could be of interest if any mesages were found but it does this every other second to inform me that no messages were found.

It is very distracting when trying to monitor my application. Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: can you make this clearly, or with some screenshot? Not very clear about it.

Comment: Ofcourse! My bad, I will sort this out in a minute! @IvanYang

Comment: Now I have updated it. Is there anything else I should provide or can clarify?

Comment: yes, can you state which operation produces this kind of message? like when send a queue to queue trigger azure function?

Comment: It is caused by having a input binding to a queue in a function. No other action is being done, no function is being run etc. It is doing this around the clock without any activity on the queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this issue, but here is a solution you can take a try.

In the **Live Metrics Stream** page -> click the **filter button** next to **Sample Telemetry** -> then in **Query Builder** popup, you can set a custom filter for the Trace message, like `Message != Poll for function`.

A screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't stop the app from sending all these traces to app insights in the first place.

Comment: @ldam, if you want to stop sending these traces messages in the first place, you should use the [filter feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#filtering) in App insights. But remember that the traces from the `Function app` will not be filtered, only the traces from the functions(like blob trigger/queue trigger functions) will be filtered.